# How to write HQL to query the data also include the bridge table column?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, hql

I have a question regarding how to write HQL query the data and also contain the bridge table column? Here is my ER diagram:

[image]

In my TeamRepository code:

```
package com.crmbackend.allService.teamService.repo;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import com.crmbackend.entity.Team;

public interface TeamRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Team, Integer> {

    @Query("select t from Team t")
    public List<Team> getAllTeamandDetails();

}
```

And here is the result:

[image]

As you can see I get all teams and all users who belong to that team.
***But question here I can't get the extra column - active from team_users entity.***
How should I write this HQL code to extra all team and users information and also the data from bridge table?

That's my question, thanks!

Comment: You might be able to manually maintain a function table along with using `@ManyToMany`, q.v. [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many) to get some ideas on how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to access this column is to map the collection/join table as entity and also map that column. If you are using Hibernate 5.1+ you can write a query like this:

```
select t, tu
from Team t
left join TeamUser tu on tu.team.id = t.id
```